# Swift_TransportException: Cannot send message without a sender address Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

MAIL_MAILER was MAIL_MAILER=smtp and i changed it to MAIL_MAILER=log to see the message email in the file laravel.log

I am using laravel 7, MAIL_DRIVER was changed to MAIL_MAILER in this version

where is the error? And how i can resolve this?

i have this in my .env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:fmT3dL+Uhb0su5Vpetm2tv2RFqF/0PxP9kY9scCu1L0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=log
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mimail@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="API Restful"

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=-----
MAILGUN_SECRET=-----

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: seems like you just added MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS `php artisan config:clear` and try again

Comment: no, it doesnt work

Comment: what do i write in mail_username and mail_passoword? or can i write anything?

Comment: Give something, I think this will help. But not sure

Comment: i close visual studio code and open it again, now it works XD

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens to someone else and OP's fix doesn't solve it, another thing to try is to remember to restart artisan serve after modifying .env (unless it is configured to detect changes automatically, obviously).